# Tensorflow GPU utilization only 60% (GTX 1070)

Tags: performance, machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow, nvidia

I'm training a CNN model with tensorflow. I only achieve a GPU utilization of 60% (+- 2-3%) without big drops.

```
Sun Oct 23 11:34:26 2016       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 367.57                 Driver Version: 367.57                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1070    Off  | 0000:01:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
|  1%   53C    P2    90W / 170W |   7823MiB /  8113MiB |     60%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      3644    C   /usr/bin/python2.7                            7821MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Since it's a Pascal card I am using CUDA 8 with cudnn 5.1.5
The CPU usage is around 50% (evenly distributed over 8 threads. i7 4770k), so the CPU performance should not be the bottleneck.

I'm using the binary file format of Tensorflow with and read with `tf.TFRecordReader()`

I'm creating batches of images like this:

```
#Uses tf.TFRecordReader() to read single Example
label, image = read_and_decode_single_example(filename_queue=filename_queue) 
image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image.values[0], channels=3)
jpeg = tf.cast(image, tf.float32) / 255.
jpeg.set_shape([66,200,3])
images_batch, labels_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
    [jpeg, label], batch_size= FLAGS.batch_size,
    num_threads=8,
    capacity=2000, #tried bigger values here, does not change the performance
    min_after_dequeue=1000) #here too
```

Here is my training loop:

```
sess = tf.Session()

sess.run(init)
tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess)
for step in xrange(FLAGS.max_steps):
    labels, images = sess.run([labels_batch, images_batch])
    feed_dict = {images_placeholder: images, labels_placeholder: labels}
    _, loss_value = sess.run([train_op, loss],
                                 feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

I don't have much experience with tensorflow, and I don't now where the bottleneck could be. If you need any more code snippets to help identify the issue, I will provide them.

UPDATE: Bandwidth test results

```
==5172== NVPROF is profiling process 5172, command: ./bandwidthtest

Device: GeForce GTX 1070
Transfer size (MB): 3960

Pageable transfers
  Host to Device bandwidth (GB/s): 7.066359
  Device to Host bandwidth (GB/s): 6.850315

Pinned transfers
  Host to Device bandwidth (GB/s): 12.038037
  Device to Host bandwidth (GB/s): 12.683915

==5172== Profiling application: ./bandwidthtest
==5172== Profiling result:
Time(%)      Time     Calls       Avg       Min       Max  Name
 50.03%  933.34ms         2  466.67ms  327.33ms  606.01ms  [CUDA memcpy DtoH]
 49.97%  932.32ms         2  466.16ms  344.89ms  587.42ms  [CUDA memcpy HtoD]

==5172== API calls:
Time(%)      Time     Calls       Avg       Min       Max  Name
 46.60%  1.86597s         4  466.49ms  327.36ms  606.15ms  cudaMemcpy
 35.43%  1.41863s         2  709.31ms  632.94ms  785.69ms  cudaMallocHost
 17.89%  716.33ms         2  358.17ms  346.14ms  370.19ms  cudaFreeHost
  0.04%  1.5572ms         1  1.5572ms  1.5572ms  1.5572ms  cudaMalloc
  0.02%  708.41us         1  708.41us  708.41us  708.41us  cudaFree
  0.01%  203.58us         1  203.58us  203.58us  203.58us  cudaGetDeviceProperties
  0.00%  187.55us         1  187.55us  187.55us  187.55us  cuDeviceTotalMem
  0.00%  162.41us        91  1.7840us     105ns  61.874us  cuDeviceGetAttribute
  0.00%  79.979us         4  19.994us  1.9580us  73.537us  cudaEventSynchronize
  0.00%  77.074us         8  9.6340us  1.5860us  28.925us  cudaEventRecord
  0.00%  19.282us         1  19.282us  19.282us  19.282us  cuDeviceGetName
  0.00%  17.891us         4  4.4720us     629ns  8.6080us  cudaEventDestroy
  0.00%  16.348us         4  4.0870us     818ns  8.8600us  cudaEventCreate
  0.00%  7.3070us         4  1.8260us  1.7040us  2.0680us  cudaEventElapsedTime
  0.00%  1.6670us         3     555ns     128ns  1.2720us  cuDeviceGetCount
  0.00%     813ns         3     271ns     142ns     439ns  cuDeviceGet
```

Comment: First - how big is your **batch**? And how big is your model? Could you try building bigger CNN (and pushing more data in a single batch) to see whether the problem is in synchronizing between CPU and GPU?

Comment: @lejlot he's already pretty much maxing out the GPU memory

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Tensorflow always grabs as much GPU memory as possible if you don't configure it.

Comment: @lejlot My Batch is 32 with images of 200x66x3 Thats 5 Mb if I didn't mess up the calculation! However I also tried with 128 batch and that did not change anything!! Model Size is kind of hard to calculate... I got 5 Convolutional layers and 3 fully connected..

Comment: @andre_bauer Thanks, I wasn't aware of it.

Comment: can you try something way bigger? Like batch of 2048? Not that it makes much sense, but just to check how it affects utilization. There are also profiling tools in tensorboard that you could use

Comment: @lejlot with 256 I get 40-50%. With 2048 It goes to 100% but drops to zero and then back to 100% and so on....

Comment: Which makes perfect sense - more data is needed to fully utilize GPU capabilities, but your CPU then is unable to send enough data to GPU and get results (thus drops). You could define bigger model and go back to small batch size and you should be able to utilize it 100% all the time

Comment: Even though the CPU usage is around 50%?... And if that's the case, a more complex model will need more training iterations...

Comment: Would saving the decoded images in the binary files increase my training performance? This would increase the size of the binary files enormously (more than 10 times I think), so I'm not sure if it's worth a try...

Comment: I agree, it's likely that your model doesn't have enough parallelism for the GPU kernels to fully occupy the GPU.  One things you might want to check, though: turn on log_device_placement in the Tensorflow session, and make sure the right operators are running on the GPU and the CPU. Tensorflow's placer is simplistic at the moment. CPU<->GPU copies are expensive and the placer sometimes is too eager to put cheap operators on GPU even though it adds needless copies.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After getting some more experience with tensorflow I realized that the GPU usage heavily depends on the networks size, batch size and preprocessing. Using a bigger network with more conv layers (Resnet style for example) increases the GPU usage because more computations are involved and less overhead (in relation to the computation) is produced by transferring data etc.

Comment: This is spot on. Experimenting with network layers, type, batch size, and even the float accuracy will result in different GPU usage hists.

Answer (score 5):

One potential bottleneck is the PCI Express bus usage between the CPU and the GPU, when loading the images to the GPU. You can use some [tools to measure it](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/36676/903).

Another potential bottleneck is disk IO, I don't see anything in your code that would cause it but it's always a good idea to keep an eye on it.

Comment: Whats the best way to check for Disk IO Bottlenecks? I'm using a SSD and data is Binary File. If thats the Bottleneck there is no way to improve I think :/

Comment: @andre_bauer I use `iotop` on Linux.

Comment: I got 1.7 GB (for now) of Training Data and the Disk is completely idle because I think everythink is in RAM (32Gb so there is room for more training data!)

Comment: I updated my question and added the Bandwidth test results. I think they look normal, right?

Comment: @andre_bauer yes. It's too bad we don't have a program to monitor the PCI Express bus usage on Linux.